# Extract time (HH:MM) from moment timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs

This code uses node.js moment-timezone to get New York time.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var time_output= moment().tz("America/New_York").format();
```

`time_output` looks like this `2015-11-12T05:09:49-05:00`

I would like to format `time_output` such that it is of the format (HH:MM) and looks like `05:09`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Margus gets credit for this one having found the docs specific to the case here:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Your specific problem can be solved with code like this:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var time_output= moment().tz("America/New_York").format("HH:mm");
```

For future info hunting where docs are lacking the unit tests often provide useful insights into library use cases.

The tests for momentjs provide a useful aet of examples:
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/test/moment/format.js

If no unit tests are available (uh oh!) or you need clarification the source code can be referred to.  It just so happens that momentjs source is pretty nicely structured for this kind of discovery.

The date formats are in source as a regex:
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/format/format.js#L3

Comment: Yours is the best answer, though not the fastest. I have switched and chosen your answer as The answer :)

Comment: 1) The docs for moment are extensive. There's a docs link right at the top of the homepage.  How can we make it more visible? The supported formats are with the `format` function docs, [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).  2) No, they are not the same as Java's SDF.  3) Format strings are case sensitive, `hh` is 12-hour, `HH` is 24 hour.  The format in your answer should be `HH:mm`.

Comment: @MattJohnson more discoverable docs might be page-per-module based like Node.js or JavaDocs. The existing docs are really good and should exist as well, but they aren't jumping out in search engines like the Node.js module docs and JavaDocs tend to. That may be a trickier problem.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but do know that it is a pure OSS project and we are always looking for help!  The repo for the website itself is [here](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com) if you want to contribute. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson it's a very well done project as well. I like the code and the site. I'm not really well-versed in JSDoc or any of the other systems but this sounds like a great Help Wanted item for the Github readme. People like getting their feet wet with OSS contribs and doc is a low-risk starting point :)

Comment: @ Matt Johnson, I missed out that format part in the documentation. The fault is mine, not the documentation.

Comment: No worries.  Just trying to better understand how to raise visibility of the docs.  Thanks for both your feedback.

Comment: @MattJohnson quick idea: a **Read More...** link after the examples on the front page that goes to Docs. I think that would catch people on a track through exploring the content because they don't need to scroll back even on a smartphone :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change your `.format('zz')` to `.format('hh:mm')`. 
This should work.

Comment: Amazing! Such a simple answer. I did not see it in the documentation. Thanks!!

Comment: You are using a library here.  The clever answerers guessed it correctly, but that's impossible in general.  You should include the require statements and possibly the library version.

Comment: You mean `HH:mm` - case is important.

Answer (score 1):

Following would work:

```js
$(function() {
  var datestring = moment().tz("America/New_York").format("HH:mm");
  $("#result").append(datestring);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"><div>
```

#### Edit:

For more information on format options you can check [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

#### Edit:

Slight difference:

- h - 24 hour time
- H - 12 hour time used with a A

credits to Matt Johnson

Comment: Correct answer as well. Sorry, I chose the other answer because it came first. However, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @user3293156 for what it's worth you should accept the best answer not necessarily the fastest.  This answer is correct, but gives you no tools to find future answers.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea Good point, however I find that one might prefer public docs over limited set if unit tests. In any case your answer got my up vote.

Comment: @Margus good point!  I put the JavaDocs first and the other digging techniques after.

Comment: @Margus good catch finding that in the momentjs docs. I totally missed it.  It's right there in the Parae section.

Comment: Should be `HH:mm` not `hh:mm`.

Comment: @Margus you've shared wrong information (h - 12 hour time and H - 24 hour time), which created solid confusion here, please edit your answer asap.